# Drawing and rotate image on another image in Android

Tags: android, rotation

I'm creating Android application to drawing map using `imageview`.
I'm used customized `touchImageView` class to viewing the map and to be able to zooming and moving.

Now I want to draw on that map this image and rotate it:

[image]

I'm trying to do that, but the arrow image is moving as shown below:

[image]

This code I'm used to doing that:

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
// This code to drawing the image       
    super.onDraw(canvas);   
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postTranslate(-width / 2.0f, -height / 2.0f);
    matrix.postRotate(0);
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    matrix.postTranslate(position.getX(), position.getY());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
            canvas.concat(matrix);


// This code to drawing the arrow image and rotate it
    Bitmap ArrowSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),   R.drawable.arrow);       
    Matrix ArrowMatrix = new Matrix();
    ArrowMatrix.postRotate(-Globals.theta); 
    Bitmap DrawingBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(ArrowSource, 0, 0, 125, 125, ArrowMatrix, false);        
    canvas.drawBitmap(DrawingBitmap, 125, 125, null);
}
```

Comment: tip that won't help you fix the problem:try to avoid creating new instances of classes on the onDraw function, and also avoid decoding bitmaps there.

Comment: did you mean creating two of classes of imageview ??

Comment: it was just a performance tip: try to avoid creating new instances in the "onDraw" function (like : new Paint, new Matrix, bitmap decoding, bitmap creation). it isn't about fixing the problem. I don't know much about matrices usage in this case, but I wanted to help in what I know. if you wish, you can ignore those tips.

Comment: I think it is not the solution, but I'll try :)

Comment: i've already written it's not a solution but just performance tips.

Comment: Thank you dear, I hope anybody help me to find the solution :)